# How to loop and push objects values to array?

Tags: javascript

I have a json like:

```
data: (46) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Province/State: "Anhui"
Country/Region: "Mainland China"
Lat: 31.8257
Long: 117.2264
```

Now `data` has

```
data: Array(46)
0: {date: "1/22/20", Recovered: 0, Deaths: 0, Confirmed: 1}
1: {date: "1/23/20", Recovered: 0, Deaths: 0, Confirmed: 9}
2: {date: "1/24/20", Recovered: 0, Deaths: 0, Confirmed: 15}
3: {date: "1/25/20", Recovered: 0, Deaths: 0, Confirmed: 39}
4: {date: "1/26/20", Recovered: 0, Deaths: 0, Confirmed: 60}
5: {date: "1/27/20", Recovered: 0, Deaths: 0, Confirmed: 70}
6: {date: "1/28/20", Recovered: 0, Deaths: 0, Confirmed: 106}
```

And I have plenty objects in the json, I loop and push coordinates like this:

```
let coords = [];

getVirusData();

function getVirusData() {
  getAvailableDatasets()
    .then(combineDatasets)
    .then(data => { // It's asynchronous
      coords.push.apply(coords, data.map(item => item.Lat + "," + item.Long));
    }).then(function(entry) {
      for (var a = 0; a < coords.length; a++) {
        var pin = coords[a].split(',');
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0], pin[1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

That works but I need to also push each date for each object into an array, should be i believe an associative array tho since the dates are related to those particular coordinates and do so for each object and also "confirmed", "Recovered" and "Deaths" should go to their own array but related to each object

Desired output would be an array like

obj = ["31.8257,117.2264"]["22/02/20", "24/02720"]["recovered 1", "recovered 3"]

But I don't understand how I could do that for each object

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` to make a [mcve]

Comment: so you need each key in that map to be in a single array each and each index is pointing to to the other data indexes??

Comment: @SalehAlmohtaseb yea well, look at this fiddle console https://jsfiddle.net/w3kctuve/3/ I need each object with its own key to be somehow readable. At the moment I map the markers on the map but what if I wanted to relate the dates and the cases for each pin and be able to interact with them?

Comment: @mplungjan look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w3kctuve/3/ I need each object with its own key to be somehow readable. At the moment I map the markers on the map but what if I wanted to relate the dates and the cases for each pin and be able to interact with them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's the final goal but as much as I can you have all the data you need in the response object so why do you need to convert it? Can you describe the **product** you want? (e.g. for each item, I want to show a marker, click on the marker will show a popup with a list of dates and their recovered value)

Comment: I'm trying to help but can't see what is your inputs and what is your expected output

Comment: @MoshFeu I want to show a marker, click on the marker will show a popup with a list case numbers (recovered, deaths, confirmed) and the date but I also need to use ion range slider to filter the results by dates

Comment: So I would suggest to not map to array but keep the object. Iterate over the objects and create marker for each of them. When the user clicks on it, you could get the object's data maybe by the item's index, and only then, map the `data` array and show it in InfoWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle for filtering your inputs based on dates from the slider and `date` attribute on the input data:

https://jsfiddle.net/ku16vapg/5

```js
let virusData;
let virusDataCopy;
getVirusData();

function getVirusData() {
  getAvailableDatasets()
    .then(combineDatasets)
    .then((r) => {
      try {
        virusData = JSON.Parse(r);
      } catch (e) {
        virusData = r;
      }
      initUI(virusData);
    })
}



function initUI(initialDataSet) {
  function dateToTS(date) {
    return date.valueOf();
  }

  function tsToDate(ts) {
    var d = new Date(ts);
    return d.toLocaleDateString(lang, {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric'
    });
  }

  let dataSetCopy = [];
  initialDataSet.forEach(ds => {
    ds.data.forEach(obj => {
      dataSetCopy.push(obj.date)
    })
  })
  dataSetCopy.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b));
  console.log(dataSetCopy)

  let lang = "en-US";

  $("#demo_4").ionRangeSlider({
    skin: "big",
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    min: dateToTS(new Date(dataSetCopy[0])),
    max: dateToTS(new Date(dataSetCopy[dataSetCopy.length - 1])),
    from: dateToTS(new Date(dataSetCopy[3000])),
    to: dateToTS(new Date(dataSetCopy[7000])),
    prettify: tsToDate,
    onFinish: function(data) {
      let filtererdData = virusData.map(vd => {
        return { ...vd,
          data: vd.data.filter(obj => {
            objDataTS = Date.parse(obj.date);
            return (objDataTS < data.to) && (objDataTS > data.from)
          })
        }
      })
      updateUI(filtererdData)
    },
  });
  updateUI(initialDataSet)
}

function updateUI(dataSet) {
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(dataSet, null, 2)
};



function getAvailableDatasets() {
  return $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/contents/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series')
    .then((files) => {
      return Promise.all(
        files.filter(file => /^time_series_19-covid-.+\.csv$/.test(file.name))
        .map(file => getDataset(file.download_url))
      );
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

function getDataset(url) {
  return $.ajax(url)
    .then(csv => {
      const output = Papa.parse(csv, {
        header: true, // Convert rows to Objects using headers as properties
        dynamicTyping: true, // Convert some fields to Numbers automatically
      });
      if (output.data) {
        const labelMatches = url.match(/time_series_19-covid-(.+)\.csv$/);
        const label = labelMatches ? labelMatches[1] : "Untitled";

        const formatted = output.data.map(area => {
          const obj = {};

          Object.keys(area).forEach(key => {
            if (/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key)) {
              obj[key] = {
                date: key,
                [label]: area[key]
              };
            } else {
              obj[key] = area[key];
            }
          });

          return obj;
        });



        return formatted;
      } else {
        console.log(output.errors);
      }
    });
}

function combineDatasets(datasets) {
  if (datasets.length) {
    const combined = datasets.reduce((result, dataset, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return result;
      }
      dataset.forEach(area => {
        // Look for area with same coordinates
        let existingArea = result.find(a => a.Lat === area.Lat && a.Long === area.Long);
        if (!existingArea) {
          result.push(area);
        } else {
          const dates = Object.keys(area).filter(key => /^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key));
          dates.forEach(date => existingArea[date] = Object.assign(area[date], existingArea[date]));
        }
      });
      return result;
    }, datasets[0]);

    return combined.map(area => {
      const obj = {
        data: []
      };

      Object.keys(area).forEach(key => {
        if (/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/.test(key)) {
          obj.data.push(area[key]);
        } else {
          obj[key] = area[key];
        }
      });

      return obj;
    });
  } else {
    throw "No datasets were found";
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Plugin CSS file with desired skin-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />

<!--jQuery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<!--Plugin JavaScript file-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<input id="demo_4" />
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.